# assignment operator String object

Tags: java, object, assignment-operator, comparison-operators

I am new to JAVA programming.
I have read it in my book

```
String a="Hello";
String b="Hello";
System.out.println(a==b);
```

This should return **false** as a & b refer to different instances of String objects.

Bcoz the assignments operator compares the instances of objects but Still I am getting a **true**.
I am using Eclipse IDE.

**Example in book goes as this:**

```
String s = "s";
String sToo = "s";
System.out.println(a == b);
System.out.println(s == sToo);
```

That bit of code prints “false” for s == sToo. That's because s and sToo are
references to different instances of the String object. So, even though they have the same value, they are
not equal in the eyes of the equality operators. Also, s == “s” prints false, because the string literal
produces yet another instance of the String class.

Name of book: JAVA 7 for Absolute Beginners

Comment: No, the values of `a` and `b` refer to the same object, due to string interning. Are you sure that the book gives that *exact* example? Also note that the *assignment* operator doesn't perform a comparison at all. The assignment operator is `=`; perhaps you were thinking of the equality operator, `==`?

Comment: To see how it can return false, try `String a=new String("Hello"); String b = "Hello";`

Comment: Sorry really made the type .was thinking about assignment operator. Really sorry

Comment: If that's really what the book says, then read another book.

Comment: @JonSkeet ya I was thinking abt Comparison operator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an optimisation called [string pooling](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/187631-the-string-pool/) in which compile-time constant Strings (aka known to be identical **at compile time**) can be set such that they really are the same object in memory (saving space for one of the most used types of object). Or in the words of the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29);

> "All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are
>   interned."

Note that this only applies to Strings that are defined at compile time, so the following truly would print false.

```
String a="Hello";
String b=new String("Hello");
System.out.println(a==b); //prints false because a new string was forced
```

or

```
String a="Hello";
String b1="He";
String b2="llo";
String b=b1+b2;

System.out.println(a==b); //prints false because b wasn't know to be "Hello" at compile time so could not use string pooling
```

N.B. It is possible to cause the second snippet to print true by making b1 and b2 final, allowing b1+b2 to be known at compile time. All in all you need to be very careful and **treat string==string with considerable respect**, in the vast majority of cases you want string.equals(string) in which this behaviour does not exist.

Comment: The book (a) doesn't know what its talking about or (b) was written before this optimisation was included within java, you can only hope its (b)

Comment: the book was published in 2012 by Apress. so i think it is new .May be missing at that point.

Comment: ya it does actually print true.

Comment: @JB Nizet One last Question:  String a="" behaves as primitive and String a=new String("") makes the a String object.Is IT???

Comment: @chetanmehta No, both are objects, however the compiler tries to be "clever" and combine them into several references all pointing to the same **object** when they are known to be the same at compile time

Comment: It's not just string literals that are interned -- it's any compile-time constant `String` expression. In your last example, for instance, declare `b1` and `b2` to be `final` variables would make `b1+b2` a compile-time constant expression.

Comment: Almost good enough for a +1, but the N.B. should read "cause the second snippet to print **true** . . .". Also, I'd rather see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) quoted: "All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned."

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks for your help, I must admit I've learnt quite a bit in answering this question too over and above my initial simplistic understanding (which isn't really the idea but hey-ho)